# llamar a un codigo con un boton en Pyqt

Tags: python, botón, pyqt, pyqt4

Estoy trabajando con Pyqt y tengo mi ventana con 3 botones. El primer y segundo boton quiero darles acciones. Las acciones que necesito es que inicien otros codigos.
 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0L1ZT-zXzKlQ0tYSUttN1VKdVk?usp=sharing
Ahi estan los dos programas. Pantalla.py es el pyqt y necesito que el primer boton me ejecute el codigo de test! Probe colocando import test al inicio del programa pero me lo corre en simultaneo cuando ejecuto pantalla.py

Uso Pyqt4 y python 2.7

```
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      #Marketplace
      self.b1 = QPushButton("Market Places")
      self.b1.setCheckable(True)
      self.b1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b1))
      self.b1.clicked.connect(self."test.py")
```

Se que esta mal escrito pero es una forma de graficar lo que ando buscando! Saludos

Comment: Te corre el código de test sin pulsar el botón?

Comment: Ya corregi eso. meti todo dentro de mi funcion main y listo el tema es que cuando pongo       `self.b2.clicked.connect(self.main())` me da un error que dice`Form object has no attribute main`

Comment: Amigo creo que ya lo tienes, realmente aquí hay poco por hacer ya que no has expuesto tu codigo

Comment: estan en los links los dos codigos

Comment: Actualiza el código en drive y dime que version de python estas usando

Comment: Ya pude armarlo bien al codigo, chequealo, publique la respuesta

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma el codigo lee mi file1.py y lo ejecuta cuando hago click en el boton. Saludos

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from file1 import main

class Form(QDialog):
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
      layout = QVBoxLayout()
      #Marketplace
      self.b1 = QPushButton("Inventory Sources")
      self.b1.setCheckable(True)
      self.b1.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b1))
      self.b1.clicked.connect(self.btnstate)
      layout.addWidget(self.b1)
      self.setLayout(layout)

      #Inventory
      self.b2 = QPushButton("Not In Inv-Sources Marketplaces")
      self.b2.setCheckable(True)
      self.b2.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b2))
      self.b2.clicked.connect(self.aaa)
      layout.addWidget(self.b2)
      self.setLayout(layout)

      #Exit 
      self.b4 = QPushButton("EXIT")
      self.b4.setDefault(True)
      self.b4.clicked.connect(lambda:self.whichbtn(self.b4))
      layout.addWidget(self.b4)
      self.b4.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
      self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
      self.setWindowTitle("AOL Optimizations")
      self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('logo.png'))

   def aaa (self):
      main()
   def btnstate(self):
      if self.b1.isChecked():
         print "button pressed"
      else:
         print "button released"

   def whichbtn(self,b):
      print "clicked button Marketplacements Optimizations "

def car():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Form()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   car()
```